# Precision of double lost when reading from Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

This should be a simple issue but I just couldn't find anything on the Internet.
Here is the JSON string

```
  {"ratio":2.714,"daily":161.0,"userId":811032853,"topic":"#GOP2012","gender":"Unknow"}
```

Then when I do `mapper.readValue(*theString*,*theClass.class*)`, all the numbers after the decimal point are lost. For the example above, I just got 2.0 for ratio.

The version of jackson I'm using is 1.9.9, which should be the latest version.

Does this happen to anyone else as well? Thanks everyone :)

The *theClass* is just a class that holds all these variables. The type of ratio is double.

Comment: Please show us the source code for `TheClass`.

Comment: @StephenC It has been updated. But there is nothing in the class really. The only thing that may help is that the type of variable ratio is double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect something odd with class definition. Jackson does not truncate double values, beyond the usual caveats with binary floating point notations (i.e. if you wanted to avoid any rounding errors, you should use `BigDecimal` etc), which are not enough to cause problems like this.

So it would be useful to see definition of `theClass`. If truncation does occur the way explained, it would definitely be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with JackSon, but can you somehow try something like this....

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
df.format(doubleValue);
```